# uprobe programming on ARM Target

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I want place a uprobe on target ARMV7 Board, i have uprobe_example.ko which is build against kernel 2.6.39.

```
insmod uprobe_example.ko vaddr=$vaddr pid=$!
```

Uprobes handles interesting events in the lifetime of the probed
+process, such as fork, clone, exec, and exit.

`# insmod uprobe_example.ko pid=1461 vaddr=0x000084ac` 
 
    `[15245.267358] up: Unknown parameter`pid'`

I want to Insert this module with the above parameters, it is not allowing.

```
/*
* Usage: insmod uprobe_example.ko pid=<pid> vaddr=<address> [verbose=0]
* where <pid> identifies the probed process and <address> is the virtual
* address of the probed instruction.
*/

static int pid = 0;
module_param(pid, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(pid, “pid”);

static int verbose = 1;
module_param(verbose, int, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(verbose, “verbose”);

static long vaddr = 0;
module_param(vaddr, long, 0);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(vaddr, “vaddr”);

static int nhits;
static struct uprobe usp;

static void uprobe_handler(struct uprobe *u, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
nhits++;
if (verbose)
printk(KERN_INFO “Hit #%d on probepoint at %#lx\n”,
nhits, u->vaddr);
}

int __init init_module(void)
{
int ret;
usp.pid = pid;
usp.vaddr = vaddr;
usp.handler = uprobe_handler;
printk(KERN_INFO “Registering uprobe on pid %d, vaddr %#lx\n”,
usp.pid, usp.vaddr);
ret = register_uprobe(&usp);
if (ret != 0) {
printk(KERN_ERR “register_uprobe() failed, returned %d\n”, ret);
return -1;
}
return 0;
}

void __exit cleanup_module(void)
{
printk(KERN_INFO “Unregistering uprobe on pid %d, vaddr %#lx\n”,
usp.pid, usp.vaddr);
printk(KERN_INFO “Probepoint was hit %d times\n”, nhits);
unregister_uprobe(&usp);
}
```

Make File

```
obj-m   := uprobe_example.o

KERNELDIR   ?= $(DLI_KERNEL)
PWD := $(shell pwd)

default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) EXTRA_CFLAGS=-I`pwd` modules
    #sync.sh up.ko

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.ko *.mod.c *.symvers
    rm -f trace/*.o arch/*.o
```

Comment: 1. Is there anything special in the system log? If there is indeed an unknown symbol in the module, the log may provide additional info. 2. In addition, if you could show the source code of your 'uprobe_example' module, it would be easier to see what is going on.

Comment: What is in **/sys/module/uprobe_example/parameters**?  Do you have all three *parameters* listed there?

Answer (score 0):

```
obj-m += uprobe_example.o

KERNELDIR ?= $(DLI_KERNEL)

all:
    make -C $(KERNELDIR)  M=$(PWD) modules

clean: 
    make -C $(KERNELDIR)  M=$(PWD) clean
```

This Makefile will work fine, without any errors